# Strange Disk/Folder size issues (different results)

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, disk-space

On windows 10 x64 machine, with WD Purple Drive 4TB

I have a MAIN folder located at

R:/Backup/Main Folder

inside the that are lots of sub folders such as resources, projects, and what nots.

Now, if I right click > properties on

```
R:/Backup/Main Folder
```

I get the following results: 9.46GB Size

[image]

But if i do the same for one of its subfolders

```
R:/Backup/Main Folder/Work Stuffs/Projects/BigProject/
```

I get this: 153GB!!!
[image]

Please note , no hidden files or anything under these folders, just plain files from images to videos, and scripts, etc.

How the heck can the subfolder have bigger file size and disk consumption than its own parent folders?? How can I get the accurate and real SIZE of this MAIN FOLDER then?

Comment: Have checked permissions to these folders?

Comment: i fail to understand how permissions could cause such effect.. but i did check and all seems normal

Comment: I just had a hunch that it could be caused by some weird permissions, but this probably is not the case here. Is it possible that the system only counted files just from the "Main folder" and not from it's subfolders? Can you check exactly what subfolders, if any, are counted to "Main folder" properties? I noticed that there is staggering amount of folders. Especially in "BigProject" folder. Does that number check out? Also they are recently created. Is their size (in properties) greater now?