# Files visible in Windows 7 aren't visible in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

Can someone tell me why Windows 7 and Windows 10 grossly disagree on how many files are in a folder on an external HDD that I move back and forth between the two machines:

Properties of folder, reported by Win 7:  20515 files, 1742 folders, 14.5 GB

Properties of folder, reported by Win 10: 2462 files, 409 folders, 4.52 GB

This folder was created by copying a Windows 7 folder onto an external drive to move to a new Win10 machine, so the Windows 7 numbers are correct.  (They are my personal files accumulated over the years.  It is my desktop folder and its subfolders.)

I have already turned on "view hidden files" and set the registry in Windows 10 to allow long file paths/filenames. (Regardless, there is no way I have 10GB of hidden files.)  I didn't set up any encrypted folders in that directory on the Windows 7 machine.  I don't understand why 10GB of files are unseen by Windows 10.

I am using a seagate external drive, model SRD0NF1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files weren't missing at all, the problem was that Windows 10 folder properties does NOT report the number of files, the number of contained folders, and the size in GB correctly.  Unbelievable.  Maybe I should stick with Windows 7.

Comment: Another user encountered a similar bug: https://superuser.com/questions/1327400/strange-disk-folder-size-issues-different-results?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect its file and folder permissions.  It would appear the Windows 10 user doesnt have access, and therefore the ability see the files written by the Windows 7 machine.  Make sure the permissions allow the users to read and write all the files and that inheritance is turned on.  You might want to give the "Everyone" user full access.